# Can you publish a new standalone Angular project (esproj) directly from VS2022 to Azure?

Tags: angular, azure, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I have created a new Standalone Angular project in Visual Studio 2022 and now want to publish it to Azure.  Is there a way in VS2022 to publish it to Azure?

Comment: Not used VS with Angular as VS Code is so well suited for Angular development and you can deploy direct with the Azure plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out from Microsoft that there is currently no way to do this directly from VS2022 but it is now on their roadmap and this functionality will be added to a future release. In the meantime, I am publishing it by loading the Angular project in VS Code and doing it from there.

Comment: Why do you have to load the angular project in VS Code?

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can do it the same way as all the other projects. right-click on your solution > Publish
[image]

Select where you wanted to publish
[image]

Choose your target
[image]

Fill the subscription details and click FINISH
[image]

Comment: Thanks SwethaKandikonda-MT for your answer but the example you show is not the new Stand-Alone Typescript project types in Visual Studio 2022.  These have an extension of .esproj and do not have a ClientApp directory.  When you right-click on one of these new project types, you do not get a Publish menu item.